# How to fix this type error, after using UDF function in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I want to explode my `features`(type:  sparse vector of ml.linalg) as each feature's index and value,so I do the following things:

```
def zipKeyValue(vec:linalg.Vector) : Array[(Int,Double)] = {
  val indice:Array[Int] = vec.toSparse.indices;
  val value:Array[Double] = vec.toSparse.values;
  indice.zip(value)
}
val udf1 = udf( zipKeyValue _)
val df1 = df.withColumn("features",udf1(col("features")));
val df2 = df1.withColumn("features",explode(col("features")) );   
val udf2 = udf( ( f:Tuple2[Int,Double]) => f._1.toString )   ;
val udf3 = udf( (f:Tuple2[Int,Double]) =>f._2) ;
val df3 = df2.withColumn("key",udf2(col("features"))).withColumn("value",udf3(col("features")));
df3.show();
```

But I got error:
`Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$38: (struct<_1:int,_2:double>) => string)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2`

It is confused for me since my function `zipKeyValue` return a `Tuple2[(Int,Double)]`, but actually I got a `struct<_1:int,_2:double>`. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need UDF here. Just select the columns.

```
df2
  .withColumn("key", col("features._1"))
  .withColumn("value", col("features._2"))
```

In general case you should use `Rows` not `Tuples`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val udf2 = udf((f: Row) => f.getInt(0).toString)
val udf3 = udf((f: Row) => f.getDouble(1))
```